# How to copy a table from excel to word using pythonCOM

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, win32com, pythoncom

Is it possible to get the table from excel file and paste it to the word document saving its excel style? I didn't find adequate documentation about win32com and all its methods.

I've found a method **PasteExcelTable**, and I guess I should select the table from excel before invoking this method. I do the following:

```
from win32com import client
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open("C:/word_file.docx")
book = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/excel_file.xlsx")
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:D20").Select      # Selected the table I need to copy
doc.Content.PasteExcelTable(False, False, False)
```

And then it fails. I don't even know if I go the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! There is no need to select anything, just straight copying

```
sheet.Range("A1:D20").Copy()
doc.Content.PasteExcelTable(False,False,False)
```

Since there is no documentation I had to try everything at random.