# How to copy from Excel and paste as image in Word using Python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, ms-word, automation

How do I copy a set of cells from Excel and paste them as image in Word using Python ?

I am trying to automate some reports (in docx format). The excels are auto generated and then I have to manually copy cells from Excel and paste as image in Word.

I have done some research and found there are some libraries like python-docx (for word) and openpyxl (for excel). What I am not able to figure out is the copy and paste as image from excel to word.

Comment: Can you copy from excel and paste as image to Word by hand? It seems impossible. You can only paste it, not as image.

Comment: There is a paste as image option. It can be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an easy task. Because conversion Excel to image probably means the Python package/codes need to know how to render the excel content, which is a big step beyond read/write excel format. I don't know any Python package can do that.

Assume you're running Python codes in Windows, you may try to call COM to copy/paste directly from Excel to Word. I guess that would behave just like you manually Ctrl+C/V. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248714/how-to-copy-a-table-from-excel-to-word-using-pythoncom)

If you prefer to convert to an image, may try a VBA script. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232987/export-pictures-from-excel-file-into-jpg-using-vba)